# "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" error while pip installing selenium

Tags: python, selenium

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\trigg\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphualt3k1'

I was using the command pip install -U selenium and i am getting this error.Then i thought maybe the pip version is the problem and tried to upgrade using command python -m pip install --upgrade pip, then also same error is showing up.

Comment: do you have any other process open that might be using pip? Have you tried restarting the computer?

Comment: if you get the same error after restarting system then you may have to manually delete this file `'C:\Users\trigg\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphualt3k1'`

Comment: Sounds like this happens during de-compression.  Sometimes the compressed version of Selenium (.zip, .jar. or whatever Python uses) has duplicate entries for it's libs.  (not sure how they do that, but I've seen this before in certain maven packages and in Selenium jar 4.3.0)  Also see: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10877